# Are a model's predictions (such as for stock prices) always correct at a global minimum?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, optimization

Say you have a model, for example, a neural network with the aim to predict future stock prices in a time series.

Theoretically, if the parameters are chosen such that the global optimum is found, (not a "good enough" local optimum, but the global optimum), will the model get the stock prices correct, 100% of the time, with absolute precision?

Comment: No - the global optimum is simply the least likely to be wrong of the available possibilities given the past.  But noise and changes and unexpected events means it will not be accurate for the future, just less likely to be more wrong than the other possibilities the past might reasonably have suggested

Comment: It would be wonderful if a purely mathematical algorithm could predict the future perfectly, wouldn't it? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The global optimum here just means that best possible version of the model we can have. If I'm trying to predict how long someone will live based off of information like annual income, gender, etc., I can have the absolute best model in the world for those variables and say based on all these factors, the best prediction for this person is that they live until they're 82, but they can still slip in their shower at age 24 and hit their head in just the wrong way. Almost all data will have noise like that will render even the best models wrong sometimes. Especially something like stocks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do an example.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 100
x <- seq(0, 1, 1/(N - 1))
y <- 1 + 3*x + rnorm(N)
beta0s <- seq(0, 2, 0.05)
beta1s <- seq(2, 4, 0.05)
counter <- 1
d <- data.frame(
  slope = rep(NA, length(beta0s)*length(beta1s)),
  intercept = rep(NA, length(beta0s)*length(beta1s)),
  mse = rep(NA, length(beta0s)*length(beta1s))
)
  
  matrix(NA, length(beta0s)*length(beta1s), 3)
for (i in 1:length(beta0s)){
  print(paste(i, "of", length(beta0s)))
  for (j in 1:length(beta1s)){
    
    slope <- beta1s[j]
    intercept <- beta0s[i]
    mse <- mean((y - (intercept + slope*x))^2)
    
    d[counter, ] <- c(slope, intercept, mse)
    
    counter <- 1 + counter
  }
}
ggplot(d, aes(slope, intercept, z = mse)) +
  geom_contour()
L <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(L)$coef[, 1]
d[which(d$mse == min(d$mse)), ]
mean((y - (summary(L)$coef[1, 1] + summary(L)$coef[2, 1]*x))^2)
```

[image: Loss function level sets]

The plot shows the minimum to be around a slope of $2.7$ and an intercept of $1.2$. Indeed, the minimum occurs around there in the simulated loss function and also when the OLS regression estimate is performed. However, the mean squared error is not zero. In the simulated loss function, the MSE is $0.9703055$, and the OLS estimate gives an MSE of $0.9702297$.

Therefore, even at the global minimum, the loss function is not equal to zero, and the predictions are not perfect.

It would be nice to make a model that gives perfect predictions, particularly when it comes to predicting stock prices, but that is not realistic.